# Is there any Windows command to uninstall an application?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7

I want to write a batch file in which I need to uninstall some applications from my Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 3):

**STEP 1**: Open command prompt and type **wmic** and hit Enter
**STEP 2**: Now type command: **product get name** and hit Enter. This command will populates a list of installed applications on your PC with complete name of an application.
**STEP 3**: Now type: **product where name="" call uninstall** and hit Enter (Note: Inside name " " you have to write the exact name of software you wish to uninstall from the populated list)

**Example**: product where name="Microsoft Office" call uninstall
**STEP 4**: Type **Y** for confirming un-installation process then press **Enter** to uninstall the software completely.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Just tried that on my Windows 7 machine... not working as "product is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: This command is actually provided by the WMI Command Line, not the native Command Prompt. Info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I just found the documentation. I submitted an edit request on his behalf and I'll correct my downvote